# Spring MVC and get query parameters with Jackson

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, get, jackson

I am trying to catch other query parameters to a `Map<String,String>` 
ex : `http://url.example/route?lastIndex=10&sort=-afield&othera=test&otherb=test`
I want `othera` and `otherb` to be stored in a map. Is it possible ?

```
class MyRequest {
   private String lastIndex;
   private String sort;
   private Map<String,String> myFilters;
}

@RestControler
class MyController {
   @GetMapping("/route")
   public String get(MyRequest request) {
     return "OK";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it may work if you are going to use `MyRequest` class. Given that these are *AJAX* GET requests (since its a `@RestController`), you can use `@RequestBody`:

```
@RestControler
class MyController {
   @GetMapping("/route")
   public String get(@RequestBody MyRequest request) {
     return "OK";
  }
}
```

and send the request as JSON like this instead of using query parameters:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://url.example/route/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "lastIndex": "var",
  "sort": "there",
  "myFilters":{
    "hello": "there",
    "hello1": "there1"
  }'
}
```

---

> Can GET requests have body?

The specs are a bit *ambiguous* about it - you can read more on it [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body). But Spring Boot runtime containers (I checked Tomcat, Jetty and UnderTow in Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE) support them if you are using AJAX GET requests.

Comment: AJAX GET request with body work, I just tested in my spring boot app... because a `RestController` is used here, it *is* AJAX right

Comment: If it works or not depends on your browser and runtime used. As the specification is a bit ambiguous on it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: It works in Spring Boot though, you can try it out :) It doesn't depend on the browser in any case !

Comment: As stated that depends on the container. It might work on Tomcat, but when using Jetty/Netty/Undertow it might not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum it works in Tomcat, Jetty & Undertow, these spring containers are supporting it...

Comment: Anyway, every time I do something in SO, it brushes up my knowledge... nice talking with you :)

Answer (score 0):

As your MyRequset class contains only string parameters, it would be wise, probably to use something like

```
   @GetMapping("/route")
   public MyRequest get(@RequsetParam Map<String,String> allParams)
```

and then just convert your parameters map the way you like.